# SLA battery: Dead or not?

Tags: batteries

I bought an air compressor at a yard sale, and the battery was “completely dead” as the previous owner had said. So, I brought it home to try and fix it. I turned it on and the analog meter needle read about halfway. So the battery was not dead. So, I hook up my bench power supply to the charging port, set it to 12v (the voltage printed next to the port), and let it sit overnight.

I woke up the next morning to an unchanged meter needle. I thought maybe something was wrong with the charging circuitry, so I cracked it open, and there was the rather large SLA (Sealed Lead Acid) battery.

I disconnected it from everything and hooked up my multimeter. Instead of seeing the expected 12v, the battery read 8.3v.

I hooked the battery itself up to my bench supply, set it to 12v, and left it overnight again. When I got up the next morning and checked it with my multimeter, the battery read pretty much the same 8.3 volts as before.

Is the battery recoverable? Am I doing something wrong charging it? Or do I just need to buy a new battery?

The battery is a 12v 7Ah SLA battery.

How can I recover this battery, if possible?

I’m not entirely sure of the exact age, but the battery is definitely old. TASK FORCE # 202754 is the compressor.

Comment: No chance...... it’s well beyond recovery

Comment: Dead, alas. Keep over 12.8V at all times when possible. Any time below this, sulphation will happen.

Comment: And even fully, but not over- charged, lead-acid batteries have a useful life of perhaps five or seven years. In addition to sulfation (which occurs in the USA - sulpahtion happens, instead, in the UK), lead oxide particles fall out of the plates, shorts develop through the insulator, electrolyte is electrolyzed, usw.

Comment: Lead Acid batteries will not charge at 12.0V. Use at least 13.8V. But your battery is probably already beyond repair.

Answer (score 1):

**It's kaput.**

After discharge below 2V per cell (12V for a 12V battery) irreversible changes begin to take place.

servicable flooded batteries (with filler caps) can some times be recovered, but sealed units cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Give it one more try. The current capacity of your charger should be around C/5 where C is the capacity in Ah. So the charger for your 7Ah cell will need to be current limited to around 1.5A. To accomplish this set the current limit of your power supply to 1.5 Amps and the voltage to about 13.5 volts. When you connect it your power supply will be in current limit mode and when charge is reached it will drop out of current limit mode and go into constant voltage. If that happens it is ok and you should get your nominal 12V.

Comment: When hooked up to my bench power supply, the battery didn't draw _any_ current. I thought maybe it was just below the 0.01 amps the display can show, but I guess the battery really is dead. A new battery probably isn't that expensive anyway.

Comment: Sorry we tried. Before you order you may want a larger one you never know.